# Refreshing ListView from Custom Adapter Class - Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, listview, nullpointerexception

I want to refresh data in ListFragment from my custom adapter class, but got the error NullPointerException.

This is Adaper class method:

```
b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            BasketFragment basketFragment = new BasketFragment();
            basketFragment.getBsketList();

        }
    });
```

And when I call it in my Fragment class I get  java.lang.NullPointerException at `mDataBase = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();`

getBasketList():

```
public void refreshList() {

    dbAdaper.setArrayMyData(selectAll());
    dbAdaper.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

And here is the part where I got the error:

```
 public ArrayList<BasketData> selectAll() {

    Cursor mCursor = null;
    dbHelper = new DBHelper(getActivity());
    mDataBase = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();//NullPointerException
    mCursor = mDataBase.query("orderTable", null, null, null, null, null, null);
```

LogCat:

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:224)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
        at com.epon.fragments.BasketFragment.selectAll(BasketFragment.java:100)
        at com.epon.fragments.BasketFragment.getBsketList(BasketFragment.java:142)
        at com.epon.adapters.DBBasketAdapter$2.onClick(DBBasketAdapter.java:177)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the context right?

- [Android: NullPointerException on getWritableDatabase()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7398802/android-nullpointerexception-on-getwritabledatabase)
- [NullPointerException on getWritableDatabase()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11897426/nullpointerexception-on-getwritabledatabase)

I think that his is your problem a problem.

Maybe if this is not helping posting the content of getActivity() might be helpful?

**edit**

Your logcat makes me keep thinking that its a context error!

Comment: Yeap... I can to refresh data inside Fragment.